# How to refactor few onChange functions into one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, input

I have few inputs in component and each of them have onChange to change their value. How can i simplify this code so i don't write x similar functions? If item will have 6 inputs so I will have to copy this functions 6 times and change only one word in it (item.x) which looks pointless but I cant figure out how to make it better.

onChange functions:

```
  const changeItemName = (event: any, id: string ) => {
    const newItems: any = [...items]
    const item: any = newItems.find((item:any) => item.id === id);
    item.name = event.target.value;
    setItems(newItems);
  }

  const changeItemDescription = (event: any, id: string ) => {
    const newItems: any = [...items]
    const item: any = newItems.find((item:any) => item.id === id);
    item.description = event.target.value;
    setItems(newItems);  
}
```

Inputs:

```
        <input 
          type='text' 
          name="name" 
          className='item-info-text' 
          placeholder='Nazwa przedmniotu' 
          maxLength={255} 
          value={item.name} 
          onChange={(e) => changeItemName(e, item.id)}
        />
        <input 
          type='text' 
          name="description" 
          className='item-info-text' 
          placeholder='Opis przedmniotu' 
          maxLength={255} 
          value={item.description} 
          onChange={(e) => changeItemDescription(e, item.id)}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function and n pass the name of the property you want to change as a parameter:

```
const handleInputChange = (event: any, id: string, propertyName: string) => {
  const newItems: any = [...items]
  const item: any = newItems.find((item:any) => item.id === id);
  item[propertyName] = event.target.value;
  setItems(newItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dynamic `onChange` function that uses the `input`'s `name` to set it's `value` on a object where you keep all the input values

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const onChange = (event) => {
        setValues({
            ...allValues,
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    const [allValues, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        description: ''
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <input 
                type='text' 
                name="name" 
                className='item-info-text' 
                placeholder='Nazwa przedmniotu' 
                maxLength={255} 
                value={allValues['name']} 
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <input 
                type='text' 
                name="description" 
                className='item-info-text' 
                placeholder='Opis przedmniotu' 
                maxLength={255} 
                value={allValues['description']} 
                onChange={onChange}
              />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding [event.target.name] to item:

```
item[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply create one onChange handler in which you can set the values dynamically

```
 const onChangeHandler=(event)=>{
    items[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

it will store all the fields value in the items array